# Error SQL statement for Inserting data with timestamps into Postgres from Go

Tags: sql, postgresql, go

I need to converting a statement from MySQL to Postgres. The error is on this statement "INTERVAL $3 DAY". I am following a certain tutorial on building web apps using Go.

MySQL -  insrt:= `INSERT INTO snippets (title, content, created, expires) VALUES(?, ?, UTC_TIMESTAMP(), DATE_ADD(UTC_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL ? DAY))`

My current statement Postgres  insrt:= `INSERT INTO snippets (title, content, created, expires) VALUES ($1, $2, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL $3 DAY)`

I tried changing the statement using chat GPT but I stuck there.
"ERROR: syntax error at or near "$3" (SQLSTATE 42601)"

Comment: $3 seems to be a placeholder for parameters, but you seem to pass it on to the sql engine without substituting a parameter value into it.

Answer (score 2):

According to chat GPT 4 with my prompting I get this code snippet below, I have tried to test it and it worked, according to my GPT result gives 10 days ahead of its time as expected.

```
insrt:= INSERT INTO snippets (title, content, created, expires) VALUES ($1, $2, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + $3 * INTERVAL '1 day')
```

Another approach of mine incase interval is unknown;

```
insrt:= INSERT INTO snippets (title, content, created, expires) VALUES ($1, $2, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + CAST($3 AS INTERVAL))
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Looks good, multiplying an interval by a number works: https://dbfiddle.uk/dKsqrmlM

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html) says the argument to `interval` is a string.  You could try:

```
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL '$3 DAY'
```

Reading a tutorial like [Go: working with PostgreSQL](https://artpav.hashnode.dev/go-working-with-postgresql) might be helpful.

Comment: this will not work; a parameter placeholder inside a string literal will not be replaced with the parameter value.